# need help understanding Apache Commons Math BracketFinder

Tags: math, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, apache-commons-math

I will start off by saying that this feels like it should be easy... but it's not entirely obvious to me.  I am trying to use the BrentOptimizer to find local minima and maxima of a function.  I have an idea of the periodicity of these, and I feel like I should be able to use the BracketFinder to bracket the optimums and then send that off to the BrentOptimizer.

Her is the documentation: http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/optimization/univariate/BracketFinder.html

So for a simple case, consider:

```
f(x) = sin(x)
```

We know that there is a max at Pi/2 and a min at 3Pi/2.  If I were starting at zero and moving along the function, how would I go looking for that root at Pi/2?  It really comes down to the constructor arguments and the initial points.  Are there any best practices (assuming you know a little bit about the shape of your function) that I can use to set these parameters in a reasonable way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have probably sorted this out by now, but the bracketing method does not expect any initial points at all, the intention with `BracketFinder` is to find a starting guess that you should apply in your call to the [BrentOptimizer](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/univariate/BrentOptimizer.html). It should be OK to apply the default constructor in `BracketFinder`.

After having received bracketing points, use the three-point [`optimize`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/univariate/BaseAbstractUnivariateOptimizer.html#optimize%28int,%20org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction,%20org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.GoalType,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) method defined in the abstract base class [BaseAbstractUnivariateOptimizer](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/univariate/BaseAbstractUnivariateOptimizer.html), where `min`, `max`, `startValue` are taken from the `BracketFinder`:s `getLo()`, `getHi()` and `getMid()`, respectively.

The [BracketFinder](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/univariate/BracketFinder.java?view=markup) implementation is obviously based on the one found in [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), chapter 10.1 in the C version of the book. This could give you some more background on the bracketing principles used.